# Null Pointer exception in LiveRelationShipImpl MSM Api AEM?

Tags: aem, aem-6

Getting NullPointerException at rangeIterator.next() due to Error in inheritRolloutConfig in particular one live copy not in all live copies return by

```
RangeIterator rangeIterator = liveRelManager
                .getLiveRelationships(resourceResolver.getResource(childPage.getPath()), "", null);
```

I have attached screen shot of error

I have checked source and target(live copy ) every page is activated and

```
RangeIterator rangeIterator = liveRelManager
                .getLiveRelationships(resourceResolver.getResource(childPage.getPath()), "", null);

while(rangeIterator.hasNext())
{
liveCopy = (LiveRelationship) rangeIterator.next(); //Here Null pointer exception is coming 
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Begin by analyzing the outputs of:

1) http://host:port/content/path/to/bluprint/page.blueprint.json?&maxSize=500&advancedStatus=true&returnRelationships=true&msm%3Atrigger=ROLLOUT

Use on a Blueprint page to retrieve the list of all livecopies linked to it , with advanced LC status.

2) http://host:port/content/path/to/bluprint/page.msm.json

Use on Livecopy pages to get advanced information on their connection with their Blueprint page. If the page is not a Livecopy , nothing is returned. 

Reference: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/troubleshooting-aem-msm-issues.html

Answer (score 0):

An NPE should never occur when calling a 3rd part API (you did not write) unless the javadoc explicitly state it.

Please open a ticket with Adobe. This is clearly a product bug that must be addressed. Adobe might have a work-around or a mitigation for this issue. Feel free to report that back here.

Comment: True . 3rd Party API should not through NPE.